# Install GRASS GIS extension r.pi including r.pi.prox and implement the Addon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, spatial-statistics, extensions

I would like to install the **GRASS GIS addon r.pi within QGIS**,

***I only have access to basic GRASS commands***

I installed QGIS using the **osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe** advanced installation using the http://osgeo4w-oslandia.com

Downloadsite and I installed GRASS GIS 7.4.1 where I was able to install four r.pi commands (r.pi.cor.mw, r.pi.grow, r.pi.lm, r.pi.rectangle) using following command:

`g.extension extension=r.pi -s`

but I need to compile the r.pi.prox (Calculation of Proximity and Modified Proximity Index for patches in buffer region).

The command:

`g.extension extension=r.pi.prox -s`

returns:

> ERROR: Extension  not found

And I don't know how to implement the extensions (Addons) in QGIS.

Comment: There is a description for QGIS 2.18 how to customise grass commands: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#customizing-the-grass-toolbox

Comment: Is it possible that I need to compile r.pi into GRASS? Could this entry in the GRASS wiki describe the solution? https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install#Compiled_modules

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a compile error on our Windows build host for GRASS GIS Addons as g.extension should install all r.pi modules directly.

I have opened a ticket for that: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3642